# JSON object array write to PHP then to Database

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, post

I need to send a whole database that I created on my emulator over to my server. Just learned about JSON.

Starting simple, I tried this code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            try {
                jsonObject.put("comment", "OK1");
                jsonObject.put("category", "pro1");                 

                String message = jsonObject.toString();
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(message);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
```

and my PHP is

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$comment = $obj->{'comment'};
$category = $obj->{'category'};
$sql = "INSERT INTO test1 (comment, category) VALUES ('$comment', '$category')";
```

and I'm able to put the objects into my tables. Now I want to create an Array such that I can have multiple objects (I'm assuming this is the correct way to do it? So like if I have multiple dogs with a name and age attached to it, I would put them into an array, right?)

I tried this code below with just one object in my array and it doesn't print anything into my database. I haven't changed my PHP code because I don't know what I would change.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("comment", "OK1");
                jsonObject.put("category", "pro1");
                jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

                String message = jsonArray.toString();
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

                wr.write(message);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
```

Assuming this is the correct way to do it, putting the objects into the array and then writing them out, how do I eventually cycle through the array if I have 2 or 3 objects to send?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 

// Decode into array instead of stdclass
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

// Loop each object in the outer array
foreach ($arr as $obj) {
    $comment = $obj['comment'];
    $category = $obj['category'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test1 (comment, category) VALUES ('$comment', '$category')"; 
}
```

Comment: I replaced my code of what I wrote above for the PHP portion with your's and nothing gets posted into my database :(

Comment: @Pam It is not the entire code, it serves for illustration. The idea is to have a loop and then do what you already do inside that loop. That should insert a new row for each object.